MUI Custom Grid issue for different viewport
I am planning to write a custom mui grid. Grid will behave differently for different viewport.
for XL it is working as expected but not for tablet and small device viewport.
For Tablet, I need gutter 24px and width of each item inside container auto where margin outside container, will be 37px.
For small device, columns would be 4 and width will be auto and gutter will be 8px
working code for XL is as below


import React from "react";
import Grid2 from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2"; // MUI Grid2
import { SxProps, Theme } from "@mui/material";

interface MyGridProps {
  container?: boolean;
  gridColumn?: number;
  size?: { [key: string]: number }; // Responsive sizes
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>; // Accept custom styles
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const MyGrid: React.FC<MyGridProps> = ({
  container = false,
  gridColumn = 12,
  size,
  sx = {},
  children,
}) => {
  
  const calculateItemStyles = (breakpoint: string): SxProps<Theme> => {
    if (size && size[breakpoint]) {
      const cols = size[breakpoint];
      const width = cols * 70; // Each column is 70px wide

      return {
        flexBasis: `${width}px`,
        maxWidth: `${width}px`,
      };
    }
    return {};
  };

  return (
    <Grid2
      container={container}
      columns={gridColumn}
      sx={{
        ...(container && {
          borderSizing: "border-box",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          justifyContent: "center",
          gap: "32px", // Default gap for container
          "@media (min-width:1440px)": {
            gap: "32px",
          },
        }),
        ...(!container && {
          ...calculateItemStyles("xs"),
          "@media (min-width:568px)": calculateItemStyles("sm"),
          "@media (min-width:1280px)": calculateItemStyles("xl"),
          "@media (min-width:768px)": {
            ...calculateItemStyles("md"),
            gap: '24px'
          },

        }),
        ...sx, // Merge custom styles
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Grid2>
  );
};

export default MyGrid;



